# asp.net mvc jquery ajax request is adding to parameter values when I request more than once

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have ajax request,

```
        onLanguageSelection: function () {
            $("#submitLocalizationVm")
                .click(function (event) {
                    var localizationId = $("#surveySectionsLocalizationList option:selected").val();
                    var surveySectionId = $("#SurveySectionId").val();
                    if (localizationId) {
                        LinkAjax.ajaxRequest($localizationEditVmUrl += surveySectionId + "&localizationId=" + localizationId,
                        "random data",
                        "localizationPartial",
                        null,
                        null,
                        localizationSelectList.populateLocalizationViewModel);
                    }
                });
        },
```

I have an mvc controller with the following method.

```
   public string GetEditLocalizationInformation(Guid surveySectionID, Guid localizationId)
        {
            //...
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
        }
```

I am getting an error. The first time I make a request with the parmaeters `surveySectinID = 2 and localizationId = 3` it is successful. If I make another request without refreshing the page with the parmeters `surveySectinID = 2 and localizationId = 4` then `localizationId` will concatenate both values from the request and become `34`. What is going on here? The ajax request is sending the correct values through.

Comment: Are yous sure that the ajax is sending correct data? how did you confirm that?

Comment: With the dev tools. I can see the localizationId value being sent is only 3 on the first request and 4 on the second.

Comment: And in controller you get the value as the concatenated one? What is the value of `Request.QueryString` there?

Comment: Moment, I will tell you soon.

Comment: aahhh your correct!! I was using `+=` to concatenate the string so on the second request it messed up!! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LinkAjax.ajaxRequest($localizationEditVmUrl += surveySectionId + "&localizationId=" + localizationId,
```

You have issue with above line. The $localizationEditVmUrl variable seems to be global and because you are concatenating the parameters the next AJAX requests will have the additional parameters. Change it like this and it should be fine

```
LinkAjax.ajaxRequest($localizationEditVmUrl + surveySectionId + "&localizationId=" + localizationId,
```